# How to terminate a virus stuck in UAC authorization loop without logging out in Windows?

Tags: windows, uac, virus

The C++ code below constantly asks for administrator privileges. When Windows prompts for User Account Control (UAC) authorization, we are unable to perform any actions, which means we can't open Task Manager to terminate this program. So, how can we exit the program without logging out?

```
#include<windows.h>
int main()
{
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
    BOOL isAdmin = FALSE;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY ntAuthority = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
    PSID adminGroup;

    if (AllocateAndInitializeSid(&ntAuthority, 2, SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &adminGroup))
    {
        CheckTokenMembership(NULL, adminGroup, &isAdmin);
        FreeSid(adminGroup);
    }
    if (isAdmin) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Something Evil", "Evil Prog", MB_ICONWARNING);
    }
    else {
        //MessageBoxA(NULL, "Not admin", "Not Admin", MB_OK);
        WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
        GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, ARRAYSIZE(szPath));
        SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei = { sizeof(sei) };
        sei.lpVerb = L"runas";
        sei.lpFile = szPath;
        sei.hwnd = NULL;
        sei.nShow = SW_HIDE;
        while(ShellExecuteEx(&sei)==FALSE);
    }
}
```

Currently, my solution is to press Ctrl+Alt+Del and log out. However, I believe there should be another way to terminate this program without logging out of Windows.

Comment: how did that executable ran? manually? on startup? scheduled task?

Comment: Mannually run by user. Anyway it has started, I wonder how to terminate it.

Comment: what about Ctrl+Alt+Del and select Taskmanager?

Comment: Even if you open Taskmgr, UAC will keep poping up, making it hard to select the malicious program and terminate it.

Comment: Since this is not a programming question, I guess it's best to ask on [su] instead. Or are you asking for a solution involving custom code? Can we assume we can "prepare" for such a situation and run some sort of tool in advance, before the situation actually occurs?

Comment: Sorry for that, I thought stack overflow is for all kinds of computer qeustions. I will try to ask on Super User instead. 
My question is, assuming we are already in the UAC loop, what can we do to stop it without logging out of Windows.

Answer (score -2):

The reason the UAC prompt keeps appearing over and over in an endless loop is that the code keeps showing the UAC prompt over and over in an endless loop:

```
while(ShellExecuteEx(&sei)==FALSE);
```

Change the code to:

```
WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, ARRAYSIZE(szPath));
SHELLEXECUTEINFO sei = { sizeof(sei) };
sei.lpVerb = L"runas";
sei.lpFile = szPath;
sei.hwnd = NULL;
sei.nShow = SW_HIDE;
ShellExecuteEx(&sei);
```

Comment: The question is what to do in case a malicious program does that, not how to change the demo program to not do it. The point of the demo program was to simulate a malicious program's behavior so a way can be found to take care of such a situation. Changing it to no longer exhibit the problematic behavior would defeat its purpose.

Comment: Sorry; i thought this question was related to programming; rather than how to press Win+L to terminate the program.